# Working with event stat in google analytics api

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I have the website where merchants sell some stuff. Each item has stats like unique views during last 24 hours, a week and a month and a number of visitors that clicked on "show contacts" button. Uniqueness based on IP. This works, there're huge tables that collects all (IP,item_id) pairs during the last month, and there're a lot of updates.

Today I dig into google analytics api, I would like to know if it's possible to use it instead of my system.

The fact is all this stat is private, available only for merchant, so I don't need to have all stat at a time (it's not compared etc.). So it might be requested on demand for the specific item.

I created service account, connected it to analytics data and it seems export works (based on [this example](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/quickstart/service-php)). Then [enabled event tracking](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events) for "show contacts" button.

1. For example, when user click on "show contacts" where should I add item_id? Is it eventLabel or eventValue? So, for item_id=1234 it should be
   `ga("send","event","Contacts","show","",1234)` or `ga("send","event","Contacts","show",1234)`?

I'm confused with eventValue column in Top Events report (it seems that eventValue keeps a sum of all eventValues and even caculates Avg.Value). Does it mean item_id should be stored in eventLabel as string?

2. I added second, nonInteraction event for collecting item views, `ga("send","event","Data","show","1234",1,{nonInteraction:true})`. It count all events, but I need only unique ones (performed by unique visitors) in specified period of time (day, week, month). Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) The parameters are category, action, label and value. "Value" is a metric and is expected to be an integer. Since it's a metric it will be added up. So if you do

```
ga("send","event","Contacts","show","",1234)
```

you will increment a metric by 1234, not store an id. You do not want this (especially if you have a linked adwords account, since this will be used to calculate your "return on advertising spent").

You want to use your item_id as label, however label is a string. So what you need to do is:

```
ga("send","event","Contacts","show","1234")
```

i.e. wrap the value for your label in quotes.

2) Is there anything wrong with ga:uniqueEvents for your purposes ?